# How to edit a template file dynamically during a chef run

Tags: templates, chef-infra, cookbook

I have a template file in my chef cookbook named 'Test Template', In my Chef recipe I am sourcing and updating my template file to a file '/etc/run/mn.txt' as follows:

```
template 'Test Template' do
  source 'run.config'
  path /etc/run/mn.txt
end
```

I need to update this template file dynamically during the chef run before the above "template" resource is called. How can I edit the template file itself within my cookbook before the template resource is called? I need to do this because there are lines I am adding to the template file and if I add the lines afterward to the created file after this resource block, it will just get reverted back to the original template contents during the next chef-client run.

Comment: If you are talking about the `source` template, then I would suggest not to "dynamically" update it. It will be anyway out of the scope of Chef itself. Cookbooks are typically versioned and managed in source control and Chef server, what's the actual requirement here?

Comment: The requirement is that I want to add text to my file after it is created by the template. However, when I do it, because I made changes to the file the template resource is connected too, whenever I run chef-client again, the file gets reset without my extra lines and  then readds them. I want a guard against this.

Comment: You need to find a way to assemble the full information that you need before writing to the file and then write to it all at once with one single template resource.  You can do what you want with the line cookbook, but it'll thrash on those resources every converge which is a poor pattern at at some point if you want to send a notification only if the template updates you'll find it notifies every single run instead and there's no fixing that.  There's no good answer on how to do what you want, and you need to reconsider what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the contents that you want to include in `/etc/run/mn.txt` before the template resource is executed? If so, you can use the variables property (A Hash of variables that are passed into a Ruby template file) to push the contents into the `/etc/run/mn.txt` file:

```
template 'Test Template' do
  source 'run.config'
  path /etc/run/mn.txt
  variables(
    line_1: 'something here',
    line_2: node['some_attribute'],
    line_3: a_var
  )
end
```

And then in your run.config, you could add to the end something like:

```
<previous contents of run.config>
    
<%= @line_1 %>
<%= @line_2 %>
<%= @line_3 %>
```

(Or you could pass the variables parameter a hash, and do some sort of loop through the hash keys in your template.. to make it more dynamic)